# Formatting text with regex

Tags: php, html, regex

I have two functions to format the text of my notices.

1. Converts `[white-text][/white-text]` into `<font color=white></font>`

```
$string = preg_replace("/\[white-text\](\S+?)\[\/white-text\]/si","<font color=white>\\1</font>", $string);
```

2. Converts `[url][/url]` into `<a href></a>`

```
$string = preg_replace("/\[url\](\S+?)\[\/url\]/si","<a href=\"http://\\1\" target=\"_blank\">\\1</a>", $string);
```

Problems:
WHITE-TEXT - It only changes the color if the phrase has only ONE word.
URL - It works fine, but I would like to be able to write anything in the readable part of the URL.

Comment: change `(\S+?)` to `(.+?)` -- but you will have problems with nested or overlapping tags. Why not simply replace `[white-text]` with `<font color=white>` and `[/white-text]` with `</font>` independently of each other to avoid nesting/overlap problems?

Comment: And, incidentally, the `font` element has been deprecated. You should probably be using `span` elements with classes (or inline styles, if you really have to).

Comment: Vladr, I didn't made it independently, cause I thought it wasn't good practice, but I will do that now. Just confirm it for me, it would look like this: $string = preg_replace("/\[white-text\]/","<font color=white>", $string); - RIGHT ?

Comment: Hello David Thomas, I'm using span classes, I just put the example like this to be easier to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> URL - It works fine, but I would like to be able to write anything in the readable part of the URL.

Make the URL code have the form `[url=href]description[/url]`, you can then use this simple RegExp

```
"/\[url=([^\]]*)\](.+?)\[\/url\]/si"
"<a href=\"http://\\1\" target=\"_blank\">\\2</a>"
```

Comment: Oh, that seems easy and fine ... I'm testing it right now - THANK YOU!